# How can I get the search (float right) on the top

Tags: html, css

This is my jsfiddle (with result). http://jsfiddle.net/76kmL/2/

CSS

```
header {
    background: red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 18px;
    height: 110px;
}

#search {
    float: right;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <a href="#"><h1>Code Name</h1></a>
        <div id="search">
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
    </header>
```

How can I have the searchbar aligned with the header heading? (and not below it, like in the jsfiddle)

Do I really need to use floats in order to get it aligned correctly?

Comment: Not to nitpick, but it would be great if you stripped the CSS in jsfiddle down to just the relevant rules.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, should have skimmed off the normalize and just take the tags changing headings.

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to use floats. you have many options there. one is using `display:inline-block`, like so http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/76kmL/4/ you could also use position:(ing) and or negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `float:left;` to the Title: `<a href="#" style="float:left;"><h1>Code Name</h1></a>`

```
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <a href="#" style="float:left;"><h1>Code Name</h1></a>
            <div id="search">
                <form method="post" action="#">
                    <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
        </header>
```

And if you want to lower the search input, use `margin-top:20px;` on the search bar.

Check it http://jsfiddle.net/CtRBz/

Same line : http://jsfiddle.net/WjSvG/ (margin-top added)

Answer (score 0):

Floats are (in my opinion) the most consistent way of getting a block element right aligned. Alternatively though you could use `position:absolute;` and `right: 0;` to align to the right, but that comes with it's own set of problems.

To align with the heading vertically, you've got two options:

- float the heading to the left
- Use a negative top margin.

Example using the negative top margin:

```
   header {
    background: red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 18px;
    height: 110px;
}

#search {
    float: right;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <a href="#"><h1>Code Name</h1></a>
        <div id="search">
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
    </header>
```

JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/LR2LY/1/

**EDIT**

Alternate CSS using a left float on the heading, instead of a negative top margin. Same HTML applies:

```
h1 {font-size:30px; }

#container header a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

header {
    background: red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 18px;
    height: 110px;
}

#search {
float: right;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LR2LY/2/

Comment: If using "floats", where would I then place the float: left; around the <a>, it just doesn't seem to fit in rest of my <header> code.

Comment: Yes you'd put it around the `<a>` tag, but you'd also need to make it display:block I think. I'll make an example and add it to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can define the z position with css by z-index

```
#search {
    float: right;
    z-index:99;
}
```

I got it wrong.

```
float:left;
```

for title and

```
margin-top:20px;
```

are the solution that you want, so other answer is right.

Comment: at least you are trying. z-index only works with {position:}(ing). i get where you are coming from, but read up on it, it'll clue you in. :)